# Como o aplicativo Google Play Books "bloqueia" os livros

Tags: android, ios, google

Estamos desenvolvendo um aplicativo semelhante ao *Google Play Books* para a Instituição que trabalho, gostaria de saber como funciona o processo para o arquivo ficar "privado" ao aplicativo, bloqueando a cópia do usuário para uma plataforma externa.

Nosso aplicativo irá ler EPUB e PDF.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho certeza se é o que o Play Books faz (provavelmente é), mas todo aplicativo Android roda como um usuário Linux próprio e possui um diretório que somente esse usuário (e portanto o aplicativo) pode acessar. O que o Play Books deve estar fazendo é gravar os livros nesse diretório. É um diretório interno do celular e não do cartão SD, e portanto limitado em espaço. No Android pode ser acessado pelo método `getFilesDir()`.

Leia mais a respeito aqui, na parte de armazenamento interno:

http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

O iOS provavelmente vai pelo mesmo caminho, pelo que eu pude ver [aqui](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).